# Filtering in tidyverse based on a vector/list of possible values

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I would like to select rows of a data frame based on conditions on two columns that should identify a unique row. In the concrete example below I would like to select 
`id=1,2,3...` with a specific mtry value specified in a vector, i.e. For id=1, I just want the first line with `mtry=3`, for `id=2` I would like `mtry=5`.

I tried using `group_by` and using `filter` e.g.

```
filter(df, (mtry,id) %in% c([3,1],[5,2],[3,3]))
```

but this gives an error

> Error: unexpected ',' in .

What is the tidyverse way of doing this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create different conditions for each combination

```
subset(df, (mtry == 3 & id == 1) | (mtry == 5 & id == 2) | (mtry == 3 & id == 3))
```

Or if you want `tidyverse` put the conditions in `filter`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter((mtry == 3 & id == 1) | (mtry == 5 & id == 2) | (mtry == 3 & id == 3))
```

You can combine condition 1 and 3 to do

```
df %>% filter((mtry == 3 & id %in% c(1, 3)) | (mtry == 5 & id == 2))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. How do I do it if I have a vector with conditions without using a loop?

Comment: @Mac If you only limited conditions to check as in the example shared you could do `df %>%  filter((mtry == vec1[1] & id %in% vec2[1:2]) | (mtry == vec1[2] & id == vec[3]))` where `vec1` and `vec2` are your vectors. If you have many conditions the other answer by IceCreamTouCan would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this kind of filter with an inner join

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  inner_join(tibble(mtry = c(3, 5, 3), id = c(1, 2, 3)))
```

Example:

```
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(mtry = sample(1:3, 100, T), id = sample(1:5, 100, T))

df %>% 
  inner_join(tibble(mtry = c(3, 5, 3), id = c(1, 2, 3)))
# Joining, by = c("mtry", "id")
#    mtry id
# 1     3  1
# 2     3  3
# 3     3  3
# 4     3  3
# 5     3  1
# 6     3  3
# 7     3  1
# 8     3  1
# 9     3  1
# 10    3  3
# 11    3  1
# 12    3  3
# 13    3  1
```